# WsFederation to SSO parameters (openId)

Tags: c#, openid, identityserver3, ws-federation

This is current architecture for authentication with openId with custom SSO.

[image]

I can bypass openId(identity server) screen towards 3rd party sso with acr_value parameter:

```
context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("acr_values", "idp:Federation").Value);
```

I have an issues how to bypass on the way back.
I know I have a wreply field inside of **WsFederationAuthenticationOptions** class:

```
Wreply = "https://localhost:44300/core/wsfed"
```

This is openId identity server, to where custom SSO redirects after authorization granted.
My issue is the screen on openId layer (Please wait...). How to bypass this screen? Do I have to set up settings on openId layer or should I expect some parameter from custom SSO, like when I sent acr_values on inital request towards openId layer?

Comment: So is the question how do I get rid of the "Please wait..." screen? Or how to bypass identity provider selection when using the ws-fed plugin?

Comment: how do I get rid of "Please wait..." screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the "Please wait..." screen as it is required to handle redirection upon successful authentication using an external identity provider (your SSO 3rd party). The external identity provider will redirect back to IdentityServer, but then IdentityServer needs a way to redirect back to your application.

If you do not like the message or style, you can override the html, see: [authorizeresponse.html](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/dev/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/PageAssets/authorizeresponse.html).

Comment: The issue is there is no mentioned file in the project, just IdentityServer3 dll's once I install it via nuget

Comment: This is a common use case. See the 'HTML customization' section of the 'Customizing the Default View Service' documentation: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/DefaultViewService.html

Comment: I've just added authorizeresponse.html in template folder, but when template is overriden, it doesn't redirect to the end application. When I remove that it starts working again. Do i have to set up any settings in Startup.cs?

Comment: You included the form post like in the original?

Comment: Yes and i saw the source code, javascript files are not added inside of that page(for post redirection). I will try to add them manually in html, and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, sounds like you've fully overwritten the html instead of overriding the partial. Try adding an underscore to the file name (_authorizeresponse.html)